# google map show state and city through select option

Tags: google-maps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxni8.png)

1- How to show 30 state with marker of in google map and each state has 60 cities.
2- By default only show state with marker after choose any state then show all cities of selected state with marker.

Comment: What country?  Your question is too broad; please show what you have attempted, and what issues you encountered.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Before executing the code, be sure to change the `API_KEY` of yours. Also leave sometime before clicking the markers. In case you click them hastily, google would respond with `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` in the response and the markers couldn't be set. I just tried with 3 states and 4-6 cities of each.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 600px;
        width: 50%;
        margin:0 auto;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        var map, geocoder, oldselectedstate="Tamilnadu", selectedstate="Tamilnadu", statemarkers={}, citymarkers={};
        var cities = {"Tamilnadu":["Chennai","Namakkal","Madurai","Keeladi","Coimbatore","Kanyakumari"],"Andhra Pradesh":["Visakhapatnam","Vijayawada","Guntur","Nellore","Rajahmundry"],"Kerala":["Trivandrum","Cochin","Calicut","Quilon","Trichur"]};
        var states = Object.keys(cities);

        function initMap() 
        {
            var nagpur = {lat: 21.146633, lng: 79.088860};
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 5,
                center: nagpur
            });
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            createStateMarkers();
            createCityMarkers();
        }

        function toggleMarkers(markers, isshowmarkers)
        {
            console.log(markers);
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
            {
                markers[i].setMap(isshowmarkers?map:null);
            }
        }

        function toggleCityMarkers(isshowmarkers)
        {
            toggleMarkers(Object.values(citymarkers[isshowmarkers?selectedstate:oldselectedstate]),isshowmarkers);
        }

        function createMarker(position, icon, placename)
        {
            return new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position,
                map: map,
                icon: icon,
                customInfo: {name:placename},
            });
        }

        function createCityMarkers()
        {
            if(!citymarkers[selectedstate])
            {
                cities[selectedstate].forEach(function(city){
                    geocoder.geocode({ address: city }, function (results, status) {
                        if(status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                        {
                            var location = results[0].geometry.location;
                            var marker = createMarker({lat:location.lat(),lng:location.lng()}, "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png", city);

                            citymarkers[selectedstate] = citymarkers[selectedstate]||{};
                            citymarkers[selectedstate][city] = marker;
                            toggleCityMarkers(false);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
            else
            {
                toggleCityMarkers(true);
            }
        }

        function createStateMarkers()
        {
            states.forEach(function(item){
                geocoder.geocode({ address: item }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                    {
                        var location = results[0].geometry.location;
                        var marker = createMarker({lat:location.lat(),lng:location.lng()}, "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png", item);
                        marker.addListener("click",function(){
                            oldselectedstate = selectedstate;
                            toggleCityMarkers(false);
                            selectedstate = this.customInfo.name;
                            createCityMarkers();
                        });
                        statemarkers[item]=marker;
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAFTDif2GgY6fxV1wLRjDO9fLGzgM4NRd0&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```